# solana: command not found

Tags: validation, ubuntu, solana

I am trying to build my validator for Solana. I installed Solana on the main user.
I created another user to restrict the access to sudo. I can run the Solana command from my main user but on the limited user it says command not found. does anybody know what is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

The Solana install tool sets everything up in `$HOME/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin` and adds that directory to your `$PATH` in `.profile`.  This directory is not in your other user's path, so it is inaccessible to the other user.

To solve this, you can:

- redo the install steps as your other user

Or

- add your main user's `$HOME/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin` to your other's `$PATH`, ie:

```
export PATH="/home/$MAIN_USER_NAME/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH"
```

where `$MAIN_USER_NAME` is the name of the user that has installed the Solana tools.

Also, you can double-check the existing installation by running `which solana` as the main user.